# 500 internal server error - argument passed must be class type but integer give - symfony2

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have created a relationship between two classes in my symfony2 application. It designed in such that tableB is related to tableA I have entered data in the tableA table (as the super entity) and in my controller I am using json to make a post to insert data into the tableB table. The referencing foreign key from tableB takes an integer but when I try to make a post from postman I get this weird error

```
{
"message": "Expected value of type "\myBundle\Entity\TableA" for association field "\myBundle\Entity\Platforms#$dataValue", got "integer" instead.",
"class": "Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException",
```

this is my json format I am posting from postman

```
 {
"id": 6,
"variable": false,
"variable": true,
"variable": true,
"variable": true,
"variable": false,
"variable": true,
"variable": true,
"variable": true,
"variable": false,
"variable": false,
"variable": true,
"fkValue":3 //area of challenge
}
```

In my entity class I have this code snippet

```
/**
     * 
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\TableA $dataValue 
     * @return Platforms
     */
    public function setValue(\Api3Bundle\Entity\TableA $dataValue  = null)
    {
        $this->dataValue  = $dataValue ;

        return $this;
    }
```

**================EDITED==================**

this is how I am inserting data from the controller into TableB to the foreign key field of TableA

```
//getting the value from request
$variable = $request->get('variable');

//setting the value for persistence
$data->setValue($variable);//area of challenge
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($data);
```

I dont know if I am on the right track but can some show me how to insert data into the foreign key field using json from postman. Much thanks

Comment: Is your json being sent to api being converted to `\Api3Bundle\Entity\TableA` instance? Your setValue requires the a TableA entity, not json.

Comment: @Andrew Nolan Just edited my question could you assist a little further by posting an answer or suggestion

Comment: so if `variable` is not an instance of TableA, then you are going to get the 500 error you are experiencing. Either change your method to accept an integer as the parameter, or instantiate a TableA entity and pass that to your `setValue()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending only the key, you can use:

```
$data->setValue($this->entityManager->getReference('EntityName', $request->get('fkValue')));//area of challenge
```

Source: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html